# Italian language Math Stack Exchange Area 51 proposal

Tags: discussion, languages, area51

There are many Italian people who like to speak of mathematics and help students. Many online Italian Q&A sites about mathematics exist. But all of them lack the possibilities offered by Stack Exchange sites: no support for writing formulas, no voting, same question repeated periodically.

Many Italian people (especially students) are scared to write in English, so they don't use math.stackexchange at all.

So I went to Area 51 and [made a proposal for an Italian language math site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80735/matematica).

What do you think about this proposal? Does it makes sense?

Comment: The principle makes sense (I don't see why it wouldn't), the only problem could be volume: would there be enough users? But I guess there's only one way to know (which is to try).

Comment: [Possibly relevant discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222511/214632) about  [Stack Overflow (in Portuguese)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese).

Comment: Related: [About language-specific versions of math.stackexchange](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16517/about-language-specific-versions-of-math-stackexchange). You can read there that math.SE in Korean and in Spanish were proposed. The proposals "died" - it is difficult to find out now in which stage.

Comment: The discussion about Portuguese stackoverflow is on my side, I think... About volume: you are right, it could be a problem. But I would say that it is difficult to get volume because people not speaking in english is not involved in any stackexchange site, hence it is difficult to get them understand how stackexchange works, register, and support the proposal.

Comment: What about the MSE community becoming more accepting of questions written in languages other than english? If you don't speak the language, leave it be. On the other hand this shifts the responsibility (of dealing with the questions) to the people who speak both english and another language to translate questions, at least those in which they participate.

Comment: @GitGud The way I understand older discussions about this issue, posting a question in the different language is ok. (But the OP should be prepared to the possibility that the answer will be in English.) This was discussed [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/what-is-the-site-etiquette-about-i-asking-and-ii-answering-questions-in-a-la) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12933/should-all-the-questions-need-to-be-asked-in-english-i-saw-a-question-which-was).

Comment: Whats the practicality of creating language tags? so like calculus, derivatives, italian. Then the appropriate people can quickly find the question, respond in italian, etc...

Comment: @frogeyedpeas And what do other users and moderators do when a post in Italian is flagged "not an answer" or "offensive"?

Comment: You would have to implement some type of honor system that only people fluent in said language would make such decisions

Comment: I think that we are lucky to have an almost universal language (English) and a fully universal language (Mathematics). I know that my English is often more than approximate but I am almost sure that, because of Mathematics, most people understand. Do you think that, in this area, we should need to build national communities ?

Comment: Related FAQ: [What is Math SE's policy on posts in languages other than English?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35656)