# Answers in a language other than English

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette, policy, languages

I would appreciate if someone could clarify what the policy and etiquette are about using languages other than English on MSE, or point me to an authoritative resource on the subject.

What prompted the question is that I recently flagged a non-English answer to an English question with a comment "*thought answers were supposed to be in English*", but the flag was declined by reason of "*no such requirement exists on Math SE, though English is preferred as a *lingua franca**".

---

[ *EDIT* ] $\;$ Thanks to all who commented. Below is a summary of the main points made.

- MSE does not have an official policy on questions and answers in languages other than English. Previous discussions on this subject indicated openness to consider other languages and help with addressing and/or translating such posts in English ([1](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/what-is-the-site-etiquette-about-i-asking-and-ii-answering-questions-in-a-la), [2](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1617)), but opinions were divided, with no clear consensus.
- SE *does* have the policy of *not* allowing posts in other languages, posted under the heading "*official policy*" in a single-answer [faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/1122837): "*unless you're posting on a language-related site (e.g. French Language) or a site where all questions are expected to be in a different language (e.g. Stack Overflow in Spanish), yes, all posts are expected to be in English*".

  Moreover, a comment under the answer clarifies that "*yes, all SE sites are English-only by default, with the exception of language sites [...] and localized sites*".

  The "*what should I do if someone else makes a post that is not in English*" paragraph makes no mention of moderator intervention for such policy violations, but rather advises users to do the policing via downvotes and/or VLQ flags.
- The only MSE mod who engaged in the conversation confirmed that MSE does not have a language policy of its own, yet questions "*the assumption that the global policy applies here (which is not entirely clear...*", and is of the opinion that, regardless, violations of the language policy do not fall under mod's radar, citing the "*what should I do if*" part from the SE post.

For the record, my position is that SE policies which are not specifically overridden by a local MSE policy should be binding for MSE, that resolving policy violations is an attribution of mods, not users, and that using downvotes and/or VLQ flags for purposes other than those they were meant for is a misuse. That said, I consider the question closed and have no intention to pursue it further.

Comment: There is this post (relatively old, one of the mods decided to tag it as [meta-tag:faq]): [What is the site etiquette about (i) asking and (ii) answering questions in a language other than English?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1617) Many of the [questions linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1617) seem related, too.

Comment: I would much rather that someone post a clear and intelligent question in a language I don't understand than an incoherent or unintelligible question in English.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you, though 12 years is a long time in the life of MSE and many things changed since. I was wondering whether the policy on languages (or lack thereof) was among them.

Comment: @MJD I understand your point, but I am not convinced that's fair to either side. Not to the foreign language asker or answerer, since their audience would be more limited, perhaps by a lot, and they would not experience the same MSE as other users. Not to MSE, since the whole community-driven concept breaks down (votes, moderation etc) if large parts of the community can't read what's been posted.

Comment: If this question is mainly about answers (as the title suggests), probably the tag ([meta-tag:answers]) would be suitable here. (Regarding the age of the linked post - yes, I am aware of that. But still, I considered it worth linking.)

Comment: Related FAQ on Meta SE: [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676) Quoting from the answer there, "Unless you're posting on a language-related site (e.g. French Language) or a site where all questions are expected to be in a different language (e.g. Stack Overflow in Spanish), yes, all posts are expected to be in English."

Comment: That flag-decline was incorrect, as Meta SE makes clear: English only on English sites, other languages on those languages' sites.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist [The community here seems to believe that the official policy is incorrect.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1618/)  With respect to enforcing language requirements, I see [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2853/) as being the most relevant:  "Anyone who posts answers in other languages has to expect that most members here can't read the answer to vote it up."  I see no reason for a *moderator* to step in here.  Others are free to downvote or vote to delete---this is a community moderated site, after all.

Comment: Can't Google just translate answers anyway?

Comment: @JakeMirra Machine translation can be a decent starting point, but there are sometimes usages of words or idioms that aren't always handled well. For instance, in mathematical French, ['variété' can be a manifold or an algebraic variety](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40140/when-does-vari%C3%A9t%C3%A9-mean-manifold), and a machine translation might guess wrong.

Comment: @XanderHenderson According to  an [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/423586) by SE staff member KyleMit to the post "[Reject question titles with no English letters in them, warn about titles with too few a-z compared to other letters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390146)" on Meta SO, there is a filter in place to block questions that don't have at least one character from the English alphabet. You may want to review with the moderator team whether the filter should be active on this site, based on the policy you mentioned regarding non-English posts.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist I don't see how that is relevant.  The community here seems to have indicated that non-English posts should be *tolerated* (though probably not welcomed).  Thus this is not an issue for moderators---there is no local policy banning non-English language posts.  The fact that I will not take action as a moderator, however, does not prevent others from voting to delete or close non-English posts.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I also don’t see how your comment is relevant to mine, so I’m just going to leave it at that.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist You seemed to be suggesting that moderators here should request a per-site exception to a *technical* filter which prevents people from posting questions containing *only* non-Latin characters.  This would suggest that there is a policy permitting non-English questions.  My point is that there is no policy *prohibiting* non-English questions (or answers).  The consensus on this site seems to be that the SE-wide policy isn't a good fit for the site, but that is about as far as it goes.  This isn't an issue which requires moderator intervention.

Comment: Again, there is no local policy on Math SE which prohibits non-English posts.  There is also no local policy which explicitly *permits* such posts.  Thus the decision on how to handle non-English posts is entirely a matter of community moderation.  Flag answers a VLQ, or questions as unclear---there is no need to flag a moderator.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I would have thought the SE policy applies that "*yes, all posts are expected to be in English*", lacking a local MSE policy override, which I do not find, and you appear to confirm does not exist. Anyway, I am surprised that you, as a champion of strong moderation and a mod yourself, do not see a problem with posts in a language you cannot read. In some cases you may not even be able to tell whether the post is math, or GPT blabber, or worse. Suggesting that regular users close/delete posts they do not understand is basically asking them to do the moderation that you reject.

Comment: @dxiv You are, essentially, asking me to take permanent, unilateral action in order to enforce a policy *which doesn't exist*.  I am already being criticized for taking action to enforce policies which *do* exist.  I am not going to enforce non-existent policies.  If you would like there to be a policy, I would suggest that one of the roles of meta is to achieve policy consensus, and that this topic might be worth a new meta discussion.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I suggest _you_ bring it up with the SE mods next time you chat. They seem to be under the impression [that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange#comment1267976_13684) "***all SE sites*** *are English-only by default, with the exception of language sites ... and localized sites*". That's a comment under the official answer to the SE language question, upvoted 350+ times. I find nothing close to an official override of this SE policy on MSE so, yes, I would say that the policy _does_ exist after all.

Comment: @dxiv From the answer there:  "If someone makes a non-English post on a site other than one in the above two lists, or in a language different from the site's accepted languages, first, check to see if it's spam. A small portion of wrong-language posts are actually spam, so be sure to check for that.

If it's not spam, **vote or flag to close** it as "Needs details or clarity" (or a community-specific reason about wrong-language questions if one exists on the site) if it's a question, or flag as **"very low quality"** if it's an answer."  Moderator intervention is not required.

Comment: So, under the assumption that the global policy applies here (which is not entirely clear---many local sites have policies which contradict global policies), the correct course of action is to use standard flags (either vote to close, or flag as VLQ / vote to delete.  This is not something which requires heavyhanded moderator intervention.

Comment: @dxiv I think the summary of the comments (the portion added under "[ _EDIT_ ]") can be placed in an answer instead.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I find it odd that you conclude "moderator intervention is not required" from a policy advising users to flag the content. Are you saying the policy is that users should flag the posts and then moderators should ignore the flags? What would be the purpose of that?

Comment: @N.Virgo I believe Xander means that the regular flags like "VLQ", "NAA", "unclear...", etc. are to be used instead of flagging as "needs moderator attention" with a custom description.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist I think the summary list has pretty good visibility in the edited section of the OP where it's now. It leaves the question open and it's not an answer proper, though it could be useful for reference.

Comment: @N.Virgo "Very low quality, "Not an answer", and other standard flags send a post to the review queues, where they can be reviewed by the community as a whole.  No moderator intervention is required.  Raising a custom "needs moderator attention" flag requires the manual intervention of one of the [ten elected moderators](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) on this site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should I do about answers/questions in other languages?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26706/what-should-i-do-about-answers-questions-in-other-languages)

Comment: @DavidLui It certainly does *not* answer my question about "*what the policy and etiquette are*", and I hope you'll reconsider the dupe vote. The question you linked is dead last in the list that I [linked](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1617?sort=hot&page=2) in my post. There was no answer to that question, and the two comments under it do not provide an authoritative answer to the etiquette part of *my* question, and no answer at all to the policy part.

Comment: To whoever doubled down on the dupe vote, please read my previous comment (and my question, and the links and the other comments). It's not a dupe, not by a long shot.

Comment: If it were my question: I think solution in another language is at least as useful as no solution at all.

Comment: A new FAQ on this topic has been created: [What is Math SE's policy on posts in languages other than English?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35656)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Gratias omnibus qui annotavit. [...] Pro recordo, mea positio est, SE consilia quae a locali MSE consilio specialiter non opprimuntur, MSE obligare debere, consilium solutionis violationes esse attributionis modorum, non utentium, et suffragia vel VLQ ad proposita utentes. praeter eos abusus significati sunt. Quod dixit, expendo quaestionem clausam, et nullam intentionem ulterius prosequi.

$\color{darkgray}{\tiny\text{Pardon the French ;-) that's one reason why automatic translation cannot be trusted, yet. }}$

Comment: Welcome the Tower of Babel.

Comment: I understand this better than most algebraic geometry questions.

Comment: I accepted my own "responsum" not because it settles the matter, but because it will now require a mod to delete, so that will be an indication when/if language policies ever get enforced on MSE.

Comment: I doubt that the answer will be deleted. According the site rules and policies, it is OK.

Comment: "Expendo quaestionem clausam, et nullam intentionem ulterius prosequi." Words to live by.

Comment: this is Latin! I was wondering why the French translation did not return anything(I don't know both languages)! For anyone interested, the translation is: 

```Thanks to everyone who commented. [...] For the record, my position is that the SE policies that are not specifically suppressed by the local MSE policy should oblige the MSE, that the payment policy is violations of the attribution methods, not the users, and the votes or VLQ for the purposes of the users. In addition to those abuses are meant. That said, I consider the question closed and have no intention of pursuing it further.```

Comment: which is the last paragraph of the question

Comment: I only know two  french phrases, one of them "je ne comprends pas le français" applies here.

Comment: Joke is on you I can read Latin just fine.

Comment: French hasn't looked like that for at least 1500 years.

Comment: While ostensibly about Italian rather than Latin, this [old Meta Math.SE Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18718/italian-language-math-stack-exchange-area-51-proposal) has commentary that covered much the same ground as here.  If we are reluctant to spawn non-English versions of Math.SE, the universal applicability of mathematics urges us to tolerate and facilitate translations here as needed.  I believe I once translated a Tagalog post and facilitated communication with a textbook author to resolve the problem presented.